# Is mySQL-Connector-C is not available for download

Tags: debugging, mysql-connector

In the past the source code of the mySQL-Connector-C was available to download so people can build it locally.

It looks like this is not the case anymore.

So, how do I get the Debug version of the connector on my Windows box and OSX?

TIA!!

Comment: I see that `mysql-connector-c++` is available, but are you looking for the `c` only? If so, it looks like that the `c` versions are considered archived, but you still can find them [here](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-c/) There are other links at that resource to other things. Based on one of the other pages, it looks like mysql v8+ should be using the c++ connector.

Comment: @PaulT., I'm specifically looking for the 8.x version of `C` connector.  Can I try with `MariaDB`?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure for MariaDB, but you can check what is [available here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-connector-c/), but know that MySQL and MariaDB should be considered separate products now, having forked more than 11 years ago. What works for one DB may not work for the other as the two products get more and more divergent.

Comment: @PaulT., I filed a bug with Oracle in regards to this. Hopefully they will give some useful info... Thx. I will update this thread when I get that.

Comment: @Igor .. any luck with finding a 8.0 C API?? I'm using the C++ connector and have it working, but I fear I'll have to grab the C version so I can connect to my RDS (since they have mysqlx disabled).

Comment: @txtechhelp, what OS you are under?

Comment: @Igor .. I'm using Linux (Fedora and RedHat to be specific) .. but I found this link `https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=108119` (possibly you filed, lol) that ended up helping me get what I needed to compile the libs I need (not as easy or convenient as the old C-connector or the new C++ 8 connector, but it works) .. thanks!

Comment: @txtechhelp, yes, it is filed by me. ;-) I'm glad it helped. Hopefully when it will be resolved and the documentation is updated we ALL won't have any issues. Unfortunately mySQL is very hard to work with - no wonder the DBMS is replaced by MariaDB.

Comment: @txtechhelp, BTW, keep checking the bug - I'm sure that the fix will not be complete and I will have to file another one. ;-)